# Ceiling fan light fixture circuit breaks after power applied

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

Our ceiling fan light fixtures clicks and stops providing power to the bulbs after about 30 seconds, regardless of whether the chain switch is passing power to the bulbs or not. It has a separate light switch in the wall and when we flip it on about 30 seconds will pass until the fixture clicks and stops sending power to the bulbs. This occurs regardless of whether the pull chain is passing power to the bulbs or not. I don't see any obvious circuit breakers in the fixture and am unsure where the faulty breaker is. There is an audible click whenever it shuts off. Would this be repairable or should we look at replacing the whole fan?

Comment: Have you changed the bulb(s) in this fixture recently - perhaps to one(s) more powerful?

Comment: We have tried several bulbs including traditional and led

Comment: @ChristopherDiaz-Rose -- what were the total wattages of the bulbsets you tried?

Comment: Originals were 25 watt bulbs (same as the other fans in the house) but the current bulbs are 5w LED

Answer (score 2):

### Sounds like a faulty power limiter

Code / UL White Book require that fans have a current-limiting electronic device on any socketed lights.  The purpose is to keep people from "over-lamping" or using larger bulbs than the fixture is able to handle (thus overheating, starting fire etc.).    It sounds like that device is malfunctioning.

Code requires it be there, and spares are readily available.